# C++ Header file can not compile?

Tags: c++, header

Hi I wonder which part is wrong? After I separate my head file into .h and .cpp, the compiler doesn't work, I used to put them all in my .h file since they are just constructors. Thanks!

Graphnode.h:

```
#ifndef Graphnode_H
#define Graphnode_H

#include <tr1/array>

//using namespace std;
class Graphnode {

public:
    std::tr1::array<char, 16> state;
    char x;
    char depth;
    char direction;
    Graphnode(std::tr1::array<char, 16> _state,char _x,char _d,char _direction);
    Graphnode();

};

#endif
```

Graphnode.cpp:

```
#include "Graphnode.h"

Graphnode::Graphnode()
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        state[i] = 0;
    }
    x = 0;
    depth = 0;
    direction = 0;
}

Graphnode::Graphnode(std::tr1::array<char, 16> _state,char _x,char _d,char _direction)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        state[i] = _state[i];
    }
    x = _x;
    depth = _d;
    direction = _direction;
}
```

Error:

```
ZION:ods_v3 weeo$ make local
mpic++ -o local ods_v3.cpp -L/opt/local/lib/  -lboost_iostreams-mt -lz -I/opt/local/include
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Graphnode::Graphnode(std::tr1::array<char, 16ul>, char, char, char)", referenced from:
      _main in ods_v3-semJJ5.o
  "Graphnode::Graphnode()", referenced from:
      bfs(Graphnode, std::tr1::array<char, 16ul>, char, std::queue<Graphnode, std::deque<Graphnode, std::allocator<Graphnode> > >&) in ods_v3-semJJ5.o
      dfs(Graphnode, std::tr1::array<char, 16ul>, char, std::queue<Graphnode, std::deque<Graphnode, std::allocator<Graphnode> > >, std::queue<Graphnode, std::deque<Graphnode, std::allocator<Graphnode> > >, std::tr1::array<std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, char, std::tr1::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, char> >, false>, 2000ul>) in ods_v3-semJJ5.o
      readcheckfile(char const*, std::queue<Graphnode, std::deque<Graphnode, std::allocator<Graphnode> > >&) in ods_v3-semJJ5.o
      _main in ods_v3-semJJ5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [local] Error 1
```

Comment: Typo in the `#include` is in the real file, or just what you've written here?

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? And on which line?

Comment: What is the error message you got? Why do you use the tr1 version?

Comment: sorry modified!@tmpearce

Comment: Looks like `graphnode.cpp` isn't being built. Add it to the project like you would any other `.cpp` file.

Comment: @tmpearce Thanks....I forgot to change my make file...so stupid this afternoon...Thanks!!!

Comment: See if all libraries is compatible with x86_64 architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile looks broken or incomplete. The output suggests you build ods_v3.cpp, and no trace that anything ever happens with Graphnode.cpp that has the mssing definitions. Include Graphnode.cpp in the build or #include it in ods_v2.cpp